# How do I get required result using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT `Id`,`Amount`,'CreationTime' 
FROM `Table1` 
WHERE Amount IS NOT NULL GROUP BY `Id`;
```

Following Query Give me Result:

With two columns,and data ordered in group.

```
   ID       |   Cash    |  CreationTime
   1        |   12      |   2015-10-30 07:59:11.000000
   1        |   10      |   2014-10-07 08:55:27.000000
   1        |   3       |   2012-10-05 06:35:48.000000
   2        |   100     |   2015-10-30 07:59:11.000000
   2        |   10      |   2014-10-07 08:55:27.000000
   3        |   3       |   2012-10-05 06:35:48.000000
```

Now I want to get one row from this result, depending on the creation time of that row.
I need row with amount=3 as its creation time is oldest.

Output I want:

```
     ID       |   Cash    |  CreationTime
      1       |   3       |   2012-10-05 06:35:48.000000
      2       |   10      |   2014-10-07 08:55:27.000000
      3       |   3       |   2012-10-05 06:35:48.000000
```

I have column, "Createtime" in my table.
So please can anyone help me how can I do this?

**WHAT RESULT I GET BY USING:**

```
SELECT Id,Amount,Creationtime
FROM Table1
WHERE Amount IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Id order by Creationtime
LIMIT 1;
```

Or by using this:

```
SELECT `Id`,`Amount`,'CreationTime'  
 FROM `Table1` 
 WHERE Amount IS NOT NULL  order by CreationTime asc limit 0,1
```

**RESULT**

```
  ID       |   Cash    |  CreationTime
  1        |   3       |   2012-10-05 06:35:48.000000
```

Comment: one row based on what? top row based on sorting?

Comment: @danyal based on creation time,I have mentioned in question

Comment: I mean based on sorted order of creation ?

Comment: question is...oldest or newest. Your results make no sense if you grouped by ID.

Comment: No based on creation of that row in table,I would update question for better understanding.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey , danyal Please see my udated question

Comment: @OpenJDK thanks..I have written the answer :) execute the query please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT `Id`,`Amount`,'CreationTime'  
 FROM `Table1` 
 WHERE Amount IS NOT NULL group by Id order by CreationTime asc limit 0,1
```

Comment: while this link might answer the question, you should try to add relevant explanation to the code in order to improve the answer. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Your Solution:

```
SELECT `Id`,`Amount` 
FROM `Table1` 
WHERE Amount IS NOT NULL GROUP BY `Id` order by Createtime desc Limit 1
```

Comment: he want only one row . it will show all rows order by `createtime`

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be:

```
SELECT `Id`,`Amount`,'CreationTime' 
FROM `Table1` 
where DATE_FORMAT('CreationTime', '%h-%i') = '06-35'
WHERE Amount IS NOT NULL GROUP BY `Id`;
```

You can also use %H if you want the format in 24 hour format.